# Trying to include toolbar to Application that used NavDrawer template

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to move an old app over to the new Material design guidelines. I used the Navigation Drawer Template previously to create the Main Activity. However I am having some massive problems trying to implement the Toolbar to the main Activity. I am continuously getting NullPointer Exceptions.

I am creating a toolbar xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

After that I am trying to add it to my main layout using the include command:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.medinfo.main.MainActivity" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_database_edit" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.medinfo.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my activity_main I am doing the following:
The NPE is occuring when I call setSupportActionBar or when the Setup NavDrawer is called.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.layout.toolbar_database_edit);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }
```

I tried wrapping the DrawerLayout in a linear-layout, what that did was create the toolbar behind the container that contains my fragments, when I started the activity I saw the toolbar rendered in the background then hidden once the Container and fragments were loaded. It did however remove the NPE. I also tried creating the toolbar within the layout instead of using a separate toolbar XML file. I still got the same NPE error.

While I am asking about the new Material Design Stuff, I would also like to know if there is a way to get my EditText Widgets and Spinner Widgets to use the old Holo Theme/Style.

[image: EditText Holo]

[image: EditText Material]

[image: Spinner Holo]

[image: Spinner Material]

I am really hoping there is a simple way to revert to those styles.

Thank you for the help everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) First, your layout is incorrect. DrawerLayout accepts two children: layout container and drawer layout itself.

Simplified,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/activity" />
    <include layout="@layout/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Second, you incorrectly `findViewById` your toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.layout.toolbar_database_edit);
```

Here you're referencing to layout, but should reference to id.

Given the layout resource above, we have `activity.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/windowContentOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        . . . contents of activity layout

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

2) To use old Holo style, you should use Holo theme as parent of your app theme in styles.xml. But users would expect native theme on each Android version, so it's a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me out. Your answer worked perfectly. One question about the Holotheme, I am using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar, I don't see a Holo Theme. Sorry I am very new to tinkering with the styles xml.

Comment: You can find themes declarations in sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\themes.xml. Frankly speaking, I never tried overriding default platform themes myself, so cannot say for sure if this will be an easy task